# deprecation warning when running rails server for associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using the [letsrate](https://github.com/benmanns/letsrate) gem in Rails 4 application. I have added the gem into my lib file and changed it a bit for making it to work with Rails 4. Now I am getting a deprecated warning like this:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: The following options in your Performer.has_many :rates_without_dimension declaration are deprecated: :conditions. Please use a scope block instead. For example, the following:

    has_many :spam_comments, conditions: { spam: true }, class_name: 'Comment'

should be rewritten as the following:

    has_many :spam_comments, -> { where spam: true }, class_name: 'Comment' . (called from letsrate_rateable at /home/aravind/Documents/dev/gw-c4u/lib/letsrate/lib/letsrate/model.rb:76) DEPRECATION WARNING: The following options in your Performer.has_one :rate_average_without_dimension declaration are deprecated: :conditions. Please use a scope block instead. For example, the following:

    has_many :spam_comments, conditions: { spam: true }, class_name: 'Comment'

should be rewritten as the following:

    has_many :spam_comments, -> { where spam: true }, class_name: 'Comment' . (called from letsrate_rateable at /home/aravind/Documents/dev/gw-c4u/lib/letsrate/lib/letsrate/model.rb:79) DEPRECATION WARNING: The following options in your Performer.has_many :performance_rates declaration are deprecated: :conditions. Please use a scope block instead. For example, the following:

    has_many :spam_comments, conditions: { spam: true }, class_name: 'Comment'

should be rewritten as the following:

    has_many :spam_comments, -> { where spam: true }, class_name: 'Comment' . (called from block in letsrate_rateable at /home/aravind/Documents/dev/gw-c4u/lib/letsrate/lib/letsrate/model.rb:84) DEPRECATION WARNING: The following options in your Performer.has_one :performance_average declaration are deprecated: :conditions. Please use a scope block instead. For example, the following:

    has_many :spam_comments, conditions: { spam: true }, class_name: 'Comment'

should be rewritten as the following:

    has_many :spam_comments, -> { where spam: true }, class_name: 'Comment' . (called from block in letsrate_rateable at /home/aravind/Documents/dev/gw-c4u/lib/letsrate/lib/letsrate/model.rb:91)
```

The part of the file which generates such an error is this:

```
module ClassMethods

def letsrate_rater
  has_many :ratings_given, :class_name => "Rate", :foreign_key => :rater_id       
end    

def letsrate_rateable(*dimensions)
  has_many :rates_without_dimension, :as => :rateable, :class_name => "Rate", :dependent => :destroy, :conditions => {:dimension => nil}
  has_many :raters_without_dimension, :through => :rates_without_dimension, :source => :rater  

  has_one :rate_average_without_dimension, :as => :cacheable, :class_name => "RatingCache", 
          :dependent => :destroy, :conditions => {:dimension => nil}


  dimensions.each do |dimension|        
    has_many :"#{dimension}_rates", :dependent => :destroy, 
                                   :conditions => {:dimension => dimension.to_s}, 
                                   :class_name => "Rate", 
                                   :as => :rateable

    has_many :"#{dimension}_raters", :through => "#{dimension}_rates", :source => :rater         

    has_one :"#{dimension}_average", :as => :cacheable, :class_name => "RatingCache", 
                                    :dependent => :destroy, :conditions => {:dimension => dimension.to_s}
  end                                                    
end
```

I have tried bringing the :dependent=>:destroy to the last part of the line and changing conditions => {:dimension => dimension.to_s} to -> {:dimension => dimension.to_s}. It only throws errors. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The warning is telling you the line to be changed is in `Performer`, so perhaps your `performer.rb` model file.

Comment: this is the line it points out to letsrate_rateable "performance"
. I am pretty sure that it in turns replaces the above said lines from the gem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scope (or lambda) has to be the second argument followed by a hash of options

```
has_one :rate_average_without_dimension, -> { where dimension: nil }, { :as => :cacheable, :class_name => "RatingCache", :dependent => :destroy }
```

[has_one at APIDock](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_one)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
-> { where(:dimension => dimension.to_s)}
```